# vBulletin Facebook App not working from within Page

Tags: facebook, vbulletin

I have installed the vBulletin Facebook app for a client, and am trying to link the app page from within the sidebar on the Fan Page for the site. However, the page returned upon clicking the link is blank. I think this may be a fault on vBulletin's side (which sadly has little to no debugging facilities that I can see), possibly the referrer does not match the App URL. Has anybody come across this problem before?

Any possible workarounds via Facebook? I have tried setting the Page URL to the apps.facebook.com URL but it didn't work and through a search I've found that it's not the right approach anyway.

Edit: I have also tried iframe within an iframe, like setting the page url to a page and having an iframe in that one. It didn't work, but then again it's fairly obvious why it didn't. The last resort I think would be to see if I could reverse engineer the vBulletin code to ignore referrers or allow a different one (if it's even the problem).

Double edit: Perhaps just a way to send a link off to a new window via the app tab??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is it coming from an SSL site?  I think now all fan pages have to come from an SSL site or they will error out.  -Buddy